# Expected value of $\overline{ABC} \times \overline{DEF}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Here is a question from HMMT:
https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2013/nov/team/solutions.pdf

> The digits $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$ are randomly chosen (without replacement) to form the three-digit numbers $M = \overline{ABC}$ and $N = \overline{DEF}$. For example, we could have $M = 413$ and $N = 256$. Find the expected value of $M \cdot N$.

Here's what I did. Each digit on average is going to be $(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)/6 = 3.5$, so the expected value is $(100(3.5) + 10(3.5) + 3.5)^2 = 150932.25$. However, the answer at the link above is $143745$. What did I do wrong? Did I overcount something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistake is this: the problem asked you to compute $E[MN]$, and you responded with $E[M]E[N]$. In general these are not equal. They would be equal if $M$ and $N$ were independent, but they are clearly negatively correlated in this case; the larger $M$ is, the more large digits it received, meaning $N$ will typically be smaller.

To solve the problem, write
$$
\begin{align}
E[MN]
  &=E[(100A+10B+C)(100D+10E+F)]
\\&=100^2E[AD]+100\cdot 10E[AE]+\dots+1\cdot1\cdot E[CF]
\\&=E[AD](100+10+1)^2
\end{align}
$$
The last equality follows by realizing $E[AD]=E[AE]=\dots=E[CF]$, and that the remaining terms factorize nicely.

All that remains to compute $E[AD]$. Recall this is not $E[A]E[D]=(3.5)^2$. Instead, you need to average over all $30$ possibilities for the ordered pair $(A,D)$. That is, you need to compute
$$
\frac1{30}(1\cdot 2+1\cdot 3+\dots +2\cdot 1+2\cdot 3+\dots+6\cdot 5)
$$

Comment: We can compute $E[AD]$ with slightly less work if we rewrite it as $$ E[AD] = \frac{(1+2+3+4+5+6)^2-1^2-2^2-3^3-4^4-5^2-6^2}{6^2-6}$$

Comment: @Troposphere You've got to leave _some_ work for OP to do on their own, which is why I left that out.

Comment: Ah, sorry. (Though I see now that my rewriting is already present in the solution sheet the OP linked to).

Comment: @Troposphere Ah, then that's _my_ mistake. OP was just looking for the flaw in their reasoning, so they probably already saw that solution anyway. Good comment.

Answer (score 1):

143745 is correct. Your assumption is wrong. Just see this with the set {3, 4}. Its mean is 3.5, but 34*43 is not equal to the square of (35 + 3.5).

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is 143745.
$$
\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1\cdot(2+3+4+5+6)+2\cdot(1+3+4+5+6)+...+6\cdot(1+2+3+4+5)}{5}\cdot111\cdot111
$$

Your answer is incorrect because you average the numbers evenly

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind that expression?

Comment: $\frac{1}{6}$ because there are 6 numbers, the numerators of the second fraction is simply pairing each digit with the remaining numbers, 111 x 111 because both the digits and the one we multiply it with can be in the units, tens, hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, I did 100 million Monte Carlo simulations to see what does this distribution looks like.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from tqdm import tqdm
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
digits = np.arange(1,7)
def iteration():
    rng.shuffle(digits)
    return (sum([digits[i]*10**i for i in range(3)])*sum([digits[i]*10**(i-3) for i in range(3,6)]))
N = 100000000

mc_results = []
for i in tqdm(range(N)):
    mc_results.append(iteration())
mc_results = pd.Series(mc_results)
```

The summary statistics are:

```
count    10000000.00
mean       143754.39
std         83542.57
min         33210.00
25%         76358.00
50%        129176.00
75%        204048.00
max        342002.00
dtype: float64
```

And the histogram is:

[image]